# Escape MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

Does someone knows why the mysql_real_escape_string() function adds three backslashes before quotes, or double quotes, instead of one?

I'm seeing a problem when I retrieve content; there is an extra backslash. This happens only with Aruba MySQL server. On localhost it works great.

Could this be the particular collation? What can I do for this? (Except brute-force removal of the slash?)

Comment: Smells like double-quoting, perhaps caused by `magic_quotes`, check that setting.

Comment: Don’t feel pressurized. Only accept an answer if it really answered your question satisfactorily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem could be that `magic_quotes_gpc` is enabled:

> It is best to look at your PHP configuration file (php.ini) and make sure it is disabled:
>
> ```
> magic_quotes_gpc = Off
> ```
>
> if you turn it on and you use mysql_real_escape_string, then you end up double escaping your quotes which is NOT good.

http://www.php-developer.org/best-practices-of-mysql_real_escape_string-function-in-php/